# Como capturar o HTML da página aberta no Chrome com Delphi?

Tags: html, delphi, google-chrome

Preciso capturar através do delphi o código fonte de uma determinada página HTML aberta naquele momento no google chrome. No Internet Explorer eu sei como faz, do chrome não acho nada parecido. Alguma sugestão ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro tentar criar um extensão. Acredito que seja possível interagir com o localhost, aí você cria um servidor e a extensão serve como cliente.

Outra opção, já que teu foco parece ser Windows, é tentar (não sei se isso é possível) fazer a extensão interagir com o programa via "linha de comando".

Uma terceira opção (mais fácil e menos invasiva) é criar uma bookmarklet.

Comment: Amigo, pelo o tanto que pesquisei, também cheguei a essa conclusão de que é possível fazer isso só através de extensão. Agora preciso achar um jeito de criar uma extensão que seja possível interagir com linha de comando, você já viu algum exemplo por ai de como criar extensões do Chrome ?