# Como conseguir o código fonte de uma página HTML aberta no Firefox?

Tags: delphi, firefox

Como conseguir o código fonte da pagina atual aberta no Firefox através do Delphi?

Comment: Infelizmente, a resposta é exatamente a mesma da [sua última pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15525/como-capturar-o-html-da-pagina-aberta-no-chrome-com-delphi)

Comment: Blz, obrigado!!